# Error: Java Virtual Machine Launcher. Could not find the main class

Tags: java, android, eclipse, exception

My program was running perfectly. But, suddenly there started to come many errors in log cat. After i restarted the eclipse, i am unable to run this program.

The error it shows is : Java Virtual Machine Launcher. Could not find the main class : Server. Program will exit.

Only this program is nort running. I am able to run every other project and program.

```
public class server {

    private static ServerSocket serverSocket;
    private static Socket clientSocket;
    private static InputStreamReader inputStreamReader;
    private static BufferedReader bufferedReader;
    private static String message;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(4444);  //Server socket

        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Could not listen on port: 4444");
        }

        System.out.println("Server started. Listening to the port 4444");

        while (true) {
            try {

                clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();   //accept the client connection
                inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream());
                bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader); //get the client message
                message = bufferedReader.readLine();

                System.out.println(message);
                inputStreamReader.close();
                clientSocket.close();

            } catch (IOException ex) {
                System.out.println("Problem in message reading");
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

there is no class `Server` since your class is named `server`

```
public class server {
    ...
```

Classnames should always start with a capital letter. than use [CamelCase](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CamelCase).
This is the common naming convention